# If you have set spring.cloud.config.server.bootstrap=true, you need to use a composite configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud-config

**Problem :** how to get the data in the location **https://github.com/TEK-Leads/Config-Properties.git**

When I try to run this application, it does not showing any result, It only shows the default pass result (**see.** MessageController). or ConfigClient side logs showing
this type of massage.

**Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8888/application/default": Connection refused; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused**

When changing the **config-Server** side **application.yml** file to **bootstrap.yml**, when throwing the exception in below.

```
If you are using the git profile, you need to set a Git URI in your configuration.  If you have set spring.cloud.config.server.bootstrap=true, you need to use a composite configuration.
```

**Config Server Part**

---

**Pom.xml**

```
    <properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

**application.yml**

```
server:
  port: 9090

spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/TEK-Leads/Config-Properties.git
          clone-on-start: true
        bootstrap: true
      enabled: true
   
  application:
    name: Config-Server

management:
  security:
    enabled: false
```

**ConfigurationServerApp.class**

```
package com.ramgovindhare.configserverapp;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.config.server.EnableConfigServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
public class ConfigServerAppApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigServerAppApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Config Client Part**

---

**Pom.xml**

```
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: client-config
    
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://localhost:9090
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile:
        active:prod
            
management:
  security:
    enabled:false
```

**ConfigClient.class**

```
    package com.ramgovindhare.configserverclientapp.contorller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.cloud.context.config.annotation.RefreshScope;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RefreshScope
@RestController
public class MessageController {
    
    @Value("${msg:Config Server is not working. Please check..}")
    private String msg;
    
    @GetMapping("/msg")
    public String getMsg() {
        return this.msg;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try to add the dependency in the `pom.xml` file:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

As documented [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__embedding_the_config_server.html),

> If you use the bootstrap flag, the config server needs to have its
> name and repository URI configured in bootstrap.yml.

You did not post your bootstrap files so it is unclear if you have defined them. If you have not, that could be the source of your problem since you have set spring.cloud.config.server.bootstrap to true. In your bootstrap.properties file within the resources folder for your config server, you will need to have the following properties defined:

**config server bootstrap.properties**

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/TEK-Leads/Config-Properties.git
          clone-on-start: true
        bootstrap: true
      enabled: true
   
  application:
    name: Config-Server
```

**config client bootstrap.properties**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: client-config
    
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://localhost:9090
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile:
        active:prod
```

It also might be worth noting that bootstrap context initialization is deprecated since Spring Boot 2.4 so using bootstrapping is no longer required for this setup. More information on that can be found at https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/current/reference/html/.

Answer (score 2):

If nothing is working for you, then I would like you to try removing the below xml tag from your pom.xml in your config-server.

```
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

Also, don't forget you just need only one dependency to get started with your Spring Cloud Config Server.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```